# Reading CSV File for Machine Learning scan

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I've been stuck for 2 days making this machine learning code to work, to **read a YouTube Comments CSV file** and scan it for hate speech.
I got this code from: https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2021/07/25/hate-speech-detection-with-machine-learning/

I added a code for reading a new CSV file of YouTube Comments that will be cleaned at the def function.
The first Sample of testing a sentence **works** without any issues.
But after that I want to read the CSV file and Scan it with the Machine learning who has already learned hate speech from the Twitter CSV file if I'm correct.

Unfortunately I am not able to scan the csv file and get a correct output I wanted.
Tried many things but every time I get an different error or issue.
I think I may be doing something simple wrong. The error occures at the last 3 lines of this code.
(I've only been programming for 4 weeks so I'm kind of new to all of this.)

**CSV Files:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nAIE5gAlMOx89vhqmVpaLGYESCVJkDZk?usp=sharing

```py
from nltk.util import pr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import re
import nltk
stemmer = nltk.SnowballStemmer("english")
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
stopword = set(stopwords.words('english'))
data = pd.read_csv("twitter.csv")  # Read the twitter CSV file which the model learns from.

test2 = pd.read_csv("youtube-comments.csv")  # Let the model scan this file to see if the model is smart enough to scan this.
test2.drop(["Time", "Likes", "Reply Count", "Name"], axis=1, inplace=True)  # Drop columns we don't need in YouTube Comments CSV File

# nltk.download() # Use this if your missing packages of NTLK
data["labels"] = data["class"].map({0: "Hate Speech",  # Create labels
                                    1: "Offensive Language",
                                    2: "No Hate and Offensive"})

data = data[["tweet", "labels"]]
# test2 = test2[["Comment", [data["labels"]]]]

print("\n")
print(data.head())

def clean(text):
    text = str(text).lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', text)
    text = re.sub('https?://\S+|www\.\S+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('<.*?>+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
    text = re.sub('\n', '', text)
    text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
    text = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopword]
    text =" ".join(text)
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split(' ')]
    text =" ".join(text)
    return text
data["tweet"] = data["tweet"].apply(clean)
test2["Comment"] = test2["Comment"].apply(clean) # Cleaning CSV File Data of YouTube Comments.
print("\n")
print(test2) # Printing out CSV test data to see if its cleaned

x = np.array(data["tweet"])
y = np.array(data["labels"])

cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(x) # Fit the Data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

sample = "Let's unite and kill all the people who shot are fucking protesting against the government"
data = cv.transform([sample]).toarray()
print(clf.predict(data))  # This example works with a sentence

print("\n")  # Now I want to try to read the CSV File and scan that for Hate speech. Here comes the error.
sample = test2
data = cv.transform([sample]).toarray()
print(clf.predict(data))
```

**output error (removed some print statements at start):**

```
[40933 rows x 1 columns] ['No Hate and Offensive']

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Mango\YouTube Test
Hate Speech.py", line 64, in <module>

data = cv.transform([sample]).toarray()   File "C:\Users\Mango\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py",

line 1254, in transform
_, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)   File "C:\Users\Mango\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py",

line 1114, in _count_vocab
for feature in analyze(doc):   File "C:\Users\Mango\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py",
line 104, in _analyze

doc = preprocessor(doc)   File "C:\Users\Mango\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py",

line 69, in _preprocess
doc = doc.lower()   File "C:\Users\Mango\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",

line 5487, in __getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Images of text should either be augmented with the text, or replaced by it as they aren't searchable, or accessible.

Comment: Please provide your error trace as text, not as an (illegible) image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in

```
sample = test2
data = cv.transform([sample]).toarray()
```

`test2` is `DataFrame` and it doesn't need `[]`

```
sample = test2
data = cv.transform( sample ).toarray()
```

---

Frankly, you should get only one column from dataframe  `test2['Comment']`

```
sample = test2['Comment']
data = cv.transform( sample ).toarray()
```

---

That's all.

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code

```
import re
import string

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.util import pr

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# --- functions --- 

def clean(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', text)
    text = re.sub('https?://\S+|www\.\S+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('<.*?>+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
    text = re.sub('\n', '', text)
    text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
    
    #text = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopword]
    #text = " ".join(text)
    #text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split(' ')]
    # shorter 
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopword]
    
    text = " ".join(text)
    
    return text

# --- main ---

stemmer = nltk.SnowballStemmer("english")

stopword = set(stopwords.words('english'))

data = pd.read_csv("twitter.csv")  # Read the twitter CSV file which the model learns from.
test = pd.read_csv("youtube-comments.csv")  # Let the model scan this file to see if the model is smart enough to scan this.

# - clean -

test.drop(["Time", "Likes", "Reply Count", "Name"], axis=1, inplace=True)  # Drop columns we don't need in YouTube Comments CSV File

# nltk.download() # Use this if your missing packages of NTLK
data["labels"] = data["class"].map({0: "Hate Speech",  # Create labels
                                    1: "Offensive Language",
                                    2: "No Hate and Offensive"})

data = data[["tweet", "labels"]]
# test = test[["Comment", [data["labels"]]]]

data["tweet"] = data["tweet"].apply(clean)

test["Comment"] = test["Comment"].apply(clean) # Cleaning CSV File Data of YouTube Comments.

print("\n--- data ---\n")
print(data.head())

print("\n--- test ---")
print(test.head())

# - train -

x = np.array(data["tweet"])
y = np.array(data["labels"])

cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(x)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# - prediction 1 -

print('\n--- prediction 1 ---\n')

sample = ["Let's unite and kill all the people who shot are fucking protesting against the government"]
data = cv.transform( sample )#.toarray()

print('- sample -\n')
print(sample)
print('\n- prediction -\n')
print(clf.predict(data))

# - prediction 2 -

print('\n--- prediction 2 ---\n')

sample = test['Comment']
data = cv.transform( sample )#.toarray()

print('- sample -\n')
print(sample)
print('\n- prediction -\n')
print(clf.predict(data))
```

Result:

```
# ...

--- prediction 1 ---

- sample -

["Let's unite and kill all the people who shot are fucking protesting against the government"]

- prediction -

['No Hate and Offensive']

--- prediction 2 ---

- sample -

0        join us countdown reveal next battlefield  sta...
1         darrel swatten thx ill recruit new helper vol...
2         prez mrm great innov onlin industri call look...
3              darrel swatten copi clone bfv game base bfv
4         darrel swatten ill make  game base bfv new we...
                               ...                        
40928    origin twist steel trailer teas new plane cras...
40929                                  banzaaaaaaiiiii    
40930                           kamikaz instead v  rocket 
40931                                           emperor   
40932                                         baanzzaaii  
Name: Comment, Length: 40933, dtype: object

- prediction -

['No Hate and Offensive' 'No Hate and Offensive' 'No Hate and Offensive'
 ... 'No Hate and Offensive' 'No Hate and Offensive'
 'No Hate and Offensive']
```